# Cannot remove "recent" files

Tags: nautilus

Attempting to remove **recent** files from *Nautilus* does not work.
At times the monitor goes gray and *internal Nautilus* error is received. 
Is there command line option ? It seems it is a GUI problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a command line solution then following will help you

```
rm ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

After running this log out and log in.

Comment: I think they want to remove the entry from the nautilus side bar completely. Won't this just clear the recent list? or will it remove it completely?

Comment: @markkirby It will just clear recent list.

Comment: OK lets wait to hear from OP and then I will come back and vote if this what they wanted :)

Comment: I woulf like to remove just one file, to make sure I am not messing thing up  Yes I just want  to remove them from "recent" file list, not from HDD!

Comment: ok , thanks,. It worked with usual immediate  Unix brevity - no response , no problem. Now the final question - why did GUI told me that "preparing ..." and took forever to scan thousandths of files? And than the app closed with files still in the "recent" list.